# Zurb Foundation quick mixin

Tags: html, css, sass, zurb-foundation

I've installed and using the `Zurb Foundation 4.3.2`.

And struggling to inherit foundation's Inline-list class.

I've created a inline list using this code

```
<ul class="inline-list">
...    
</ul>
```

And from this documentation:
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/v/4.3.2/components/inline-lists.html

I understood as I can create my own class like this

```
.your-class-name { @include inline-list; }
```

in my app.scss file.

Then I wrote this code

```
<ul class="your-class-name">
...
</ul>
```

But it's not inheriting inline-list and no style. 
Am I doing correct or wrong?  Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.
I wrote wrong.
It should be

```
.your-class-name { @include .inline-list; }
```

I mistyped it without " . " symbol before inline list. 
here is wrong code

```
.your-class-name { @include inline-list; }
```